# Stain blemished/damaged surface layer in cultured marble shower?

Tags: repair, walls, shower, staining

Is there a way to **stain** what appears to be cultured marble? Two I've used in the recent past at different locations, with suction cup based hooks/holders have had some material removed over time perhaps by the vacuum/suction created. There is not, when the suction cups are removed, a whole lot of 'stuff' under them. Strange effect indeed.

What's weird is when I look this up online, all sources say you can sand it, etc. because the material is "all the same, all the way through" or similar phrases. However, you can see in my picture it clearly is not. The color cast of the photo is very poor, but the bulk of the surface is off-white, while the marbling is white, and so are the blemishes where just a very small layer of material was lifted off by some effect of the suction cups. This must actually be the rather different 'gel' based layer that I've read is what creates the surface where the material is poured into the mold. However, that doesn't really explain the technicque all the sources refer to either. Seems they would create the problem I am facing now by trying to remove colored stains etc by sanding and so on.

See Photo with three spots on left side:
[image: Three spots on left side of picture]